# How to uninstall Payssion Module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, uninstall-module

I want to uninstall Payssion Module all folder and database.
How can i do? i read this reference but not understand.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall a module through ssh if it was installed using ssh. If yes then issue command:

`php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>`

-r flag removes module data. then issue:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

If module was not installed through ssh:

- remove the module directory app/code//
- drop module database tables (if it created any)
- remove entry from core_config_data and setup_module tables

Run command

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I installed Payssion using ssh. i run this command. But show an error.

'php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Payssion_Payment'

**error :** Payssion_Payment is not an installed composer package

Comment: php bin/magento module:uninstall MODULE_NAME    => Module: Uninstall

Comment: nothing happen. 
https://snag.gy/UQEfC0.jpg

Comment: Now check Module: Status  =>  php bin/magento module:status